# I want to know how to resolve the version error when backing up postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

```
pg_dump: error: server version: 15.1; pg_dump version: 14.2

pg_dump: error: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

The error occurs. I want to know how to adjust the dump version to 15.1.

Restored the dump file backed up from the previous 14.2 version db to the new 15.1 version db.

However, when I try to back up from version 15.1, I get a version error and cannot back up. I want to know the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Install 15.latest on both client and server, and the problem will go away.